# How can I check changes to existing public api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api that others are using, and one of our developers changed the name of the action method or method parameter. Now the client has a problem. Is there any solution that, before deploying to the production server, check whether there have been changes in the existing public api (not adding new api)?

Comment: You can use git or any version control system to track changes

Comment: Write tests????

Comment: The app is too big and so are the developers, difficult to track.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the test? Now there is an idea using a swagger, or rather a file that it generates and save somewhere. And through tests to compare with the current file

Comment: You could create a swagger file with your api description. This swagger.json can easily be compared (maybe even as a task in your release pipeline) and/or you could generate a rest client api from the swagger for various languages which you can make available to your customers.

Comment: Get Postman, write a simple test for each endpoint, and then run the suite of tests against every fresh deployment to one of your test environments.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend creating a [Swagger OpenAPI Specification](https://editor.swagger.io/) for your API if you're going to be sharing your API with other teams. A Swagger definition is a specification that describes how your API looks like in terms of actions, expected input, output, etcetera. You can use such a specification as a *contract* between the producer and all consumers of your API.

Then, you can use tools like [Swagger CodeGen](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/) to generate clients and server implementations, as a guarantee that an implementation conforms to the contract. In your case, this would prevent a developer from breaking the API (unless they change the contract as well).

If you want to collaborate, I recommend placing (a copy of) your Swagger definitions in a separate GIT repo (e.g. my-awesome-contracts), give all the teams access to this repo and make any changes through pull requests. This serves two purposes:

- It gives all the consumers of your API an early notice on any changes
  you're planning to make.
- It allows any consumers to actually give feedback on the proposed changes.